# SVG to paper.js: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unterminated string constant (2:15)

Tags: svg, paperjs

I tried to add svg path (I generated it with Adobe Illustrator) to paper.js, and got the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unterminated string constant (2:15)".

```
var pathData = "M307.355,124.152c0,0-113.957,27.227-168.644-5.084
            C104.09,98.611,127.135,12.182,109.898,13.983c-24.387,2.548-72.034,42.373-72.034,42.373s-43.8,45.821-22.614,70.339
            c14.377,16.638,100.365,28.825,120.06,29.923c50.381,2.811,171.197-4.5,171.197-4.5";
var path = new Path(pathData);
path.strokeColor = 'red';
path.strokeWidth = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unterminated string constant error was caused by the problem with the format of the string. The copy-paste code had additional spaces inside the string because the error dissapeared after I put everything in one line:

```
var pathData = "M307.355,124.152c0,0-113.957,27.227-168.644-5.084C104.09,98.611,127.135,12.182,109.898,13.983c-24.387,2.548-72.034,42.373-72.034,42.373s-43.8,45.821-22.614,70.339c14.377,16.638,100.365,28.825,120.06,29.923c50.381,2.811,171.197-4.5,171.197-4.5";
```